# How to get date from a dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, dataset, datalist

I have a dataset in which I have three columns. It is a store database in which number of different goods are sold on a particular date. The date can be repeated. For example, for date one item A sold 5 units, item B sold 10, and C sold 15. Here the same date is repeated 3 times. For the next date similar data can be in the dataset. What I want is to get this date one time and make it the header in a datalist and show values of the other two columns in an inner datalist. Likewise I want to do the same for all other dates in that dataset.

Comment: Some filling and binding codes should be good.

Comment: It sounds like you want the functionality of a pivot table.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have your data loadede in memory in a typed dataset, you could group it with LINQ:

```
var query = from salesRow in dataSet
            group salesRow by salesRow.SoldDate;
// Do something with the query like iterate it, databanind it, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you can get the list separately from the database.
Else you will have to loop through and get the desired list.
`Select, RowFilter` all these function like where clause so getting distinct via that won't be possible